# Run "puppetserver ca" commands on a remote server

Tags: puppet

We are running a Puppet Open Source server. To sign and revoke Puppet client certificates we logon to this Puppet server and run `puppetserver ca ...` commands.

We would like to be able to stand-up a separate server and run these same `puppetserver ca ...` commands but have the actions happen on our Puppet server. In other words, can the `puppetserver ca ...` commands point to a remote server? If so, how can we do this?

Comment: What's the point of such a server? It would just connect to your existing server to run the commands, the same as you do now, only now you have an extra level of complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The puppetserver CLI tool only runs locally. There is no way to specify a remote host. If it is important that you be able to do this, you could run them as Ansible ad-hoc commands, but this may amount to heresy according to Puppet folks.